# Sum of all solutions

Tags: quadratics

$$x^2-2(3m-1)x+2m+3=0$$
Find the sum of solutions. It says that the sum equals to $-1$. I just can't wrap my head around this? Any help? Thx

Comment: is an $x$ missing?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the sum of the solutions (if any) is equal to $-b/a$. In fact, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutions then 
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=ax^2-a(x_1+x_2)x+a(x_1\cdot x_2)$$
and by comparing the coefficients we get $x_1+x_2=-b/a$.

In your case $x_1+x_2=2(3m-1)$. It seems that the sum of the (complex) solutions is $-1$ if $m=1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_{1,2}=3m-1\pm\sqrt{9m^2-8m-2}$$ therefore
$$x_1+x_2=2(3m-1)$$

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was thinking but in the "solution" area they are using absolute value brackets. To be more precise it states : |x-2|+|x+3|=7.

Comment: i don't know what this equation means, can you post the whole text please?

Comment: Yes sir. The question is : find the sum of all solutions of the given equation. (The equation from above)

Comment: if so see the solution above

Comment: Hmm that's what I was thinking but they say that x1+x2=-1

Comment: then it is wrong what they say or some text is missing

Comment: Okay. But I find it weird that when i plug -1 into 2(3m-1) I do get m=1/6 so for m=1/6 the solution is correct